# RecyclerView.Adapter notifyItemRangeChanged() causes re-binding of wrong views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### Short version

I call `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged()`, but see (via log statements) that positions outside the specified range are being re-bound. What could cause this?

### Longer version

My application contains a `RecyclerView` with a huge number of items. I have a counter that updates every second, and I want to modify *only the visible views* in my `RecyclerView` whenever the counter is updated. I do **not** want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or otherwise ask the adapter to completely reset the view.

To accomplish this, I use `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged()`. I use [the overload of this method that accepts a payload object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemrangechanged) so that I can do an "efficient partial update" (i.e. only update the counter view instead of re-binding the entire `ViewHolder`).

However, I see in the logs that the `RecyclerView` is binding `ViewHolder`s that I haven't told it to. For example, if positions 5 through 14 are visible on screen, I get an efficient partial update for 5-14 (as expected), but I also get a full re-bind of positions 17-24.

Additionally, when the `RecyclerView` does the full re-bind of these other positions, it sometimes calls `onCreateViewHolder()`. It seems that the `RecyclerView` wants to bind these other views, but the cache size is smaller than the range it wants to re-bind, so it has to create `ViewHolder`s (which then get immediately thrown away).

Is there any explanation for why these other positions are being re-bound? Again, these positions are outside of the range I notified the adapter for.

If the `RecyclerView` only ever called `onBindViewHolder()`, I could live with the performance penalty. But since it sometimes also calls `onCreateViewHolder()`, flinging the view causes dropped frames. This is not acceptable.

---

This problem is reproducible with the following app:

`MainActivity.java`

```js
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private enum CounterTag {
        INSTANCE
    }

    private static final String TAG = "StackOverflow";

    private Handler handler;
    private int counter;

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(this::updateCounter, 1000);

        adapter = new MyAdapter();
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private void updateCounter() {
        ++counter;

        int first = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int last = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int length = (last - first) + 1;

        Log.d(TAG, "notifying " + length + " items changed, starting at " + first);

        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(first, length, CounterTag.INSTANCE);
        handler.postDelayed(this::updateCounter, 1000);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder()");

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder() - full [" + position + "]");

            holder.bindPosition(position);
            holder.bindCounter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
            if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
                onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
            }
            else if (payloads.get(0) == CounterTag.INSTANCE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder() - partial [" + position + "]");
                holder.bindCounter();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 100_000;
        }
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView positionView;
        private final TextView counterView;

        private MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.positionView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.position);
            this.counterView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        }

        private void bindPosition(int position) {
            positionView.setText("" + position);
        }

        private void bindCounter() {
            counterView.setText("Counter: " + counter);
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`item.xml`

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#eee"
        tools:text="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ddd"
        tools:text="99"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what my sample app looks like. The text on the left-hand side is the `ViewHolder`'s position. The text on the right-hand side is the counter view that I want to update every second. I want to be able to update the counter view without having to touch anything else.

[image]

And here's a sample snippet from the logs. You can see that my `notifyItemRangeChanged()` call should update only positions 5-14, but positions 15-19 are also being re-bound, and positions 22-24 require new `ViewHolder`s to be created.

> ```
> D StackOverflow: notifying 10 items changed, starting at 5
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [15]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [16]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [17]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [18]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [19]
> D StackOverflow: onCreateViewHolder()
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [22]
> D StackOverflow: onCreateViewHolder()
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [23]
> D StackOverflow: onCreateViewHolder()
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - full [24]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [5]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [6]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [7]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [8]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [9]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [10]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [11]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [12]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [13]
> D StackOverflow: onBindViewHolder() - partial [14]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` performing extra measurement to provide "Predictive item animations" for views that might move out of, or into the screen due to (size) changes of updated views or other modifications (including `adapter.notifyItemMoved`).

You can disable this functionality by overriding [`supportsPredictiveItemAnimations`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager#supportspredictiveitemanimations) of `LayoutManager`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler);

    adapter = new MyAdapter();
    // extend layout manager and override this method
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this){
        @Override
        public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
            return false;
        }
    };

    RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

You might also (or alternatively) want to change size of [`RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool) which will prevent creation of extra `ViewHolder`s even with animations still enabled:

```
// 0 is default itemViewType, 5 is default size - for example use 20
recycler.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 20);
```

Notice how your logs have 5 `onBindViewHolder() - full` calls before pool runs out and adapter has to start creating more.

Comment: Indeed, this solves the problem for LinearLayoutManager. It does not solve the problem for FlexboxLayoutManager (even with huge itemview cache size and/or huge max recycled view count). Any thoughts on FlexboxLayoutManager?

Comment: @BenP. that layout manager does not support predictive animations in the first place (method already returns false). Laying out and updating `RecylerView` does carry a layout pass overhead to account for possible change of item sizes. If Your update is guaranteed not to cause any of them, the fastest way to deploy it is update the views directly to bypass `RecyclerView`s update logic.